# How do I add an item to the end of a linked list?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, linked-list

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, item, next):
        self.item = item
        self.next = next

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def add(self, item):
        self.head = Node(item, self.head)

    def is_empty(self):
        return self.head == None
```

I tried doing it this way but it doesn't work.

```
from LinkedList import Node, LinkedList

def insert_at_end(linked_list, item):
    linked_list.add(item)
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: No, because `LinkedList.add()` adds a new node *at the start*. Have you tried traversing the links to the end and adding a new node there instead?

Comment: replacing head everytime won't get you too far...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: actually it will. but adding to the end is the issue here.

Answer (score 2):

You need to loop over your linked list and add a new node at the end instead:

```
def insert_at_end(linked_list, item):
    if linked_list.is_empty():
        linked_list.add(item)
    else:
        node = linked_list.head
        while node.next is not None:
            node = node.next
        node.next = Node(item, None)
```

This re-uses the existing methods to add a node at the very start if the linked list is empty.

Demo:

```
>>> def print_ll(ll):  # something to print the list
...     node = ll.head
...     while node is not None:
...         print node.item,
...         node = node.next
...
>>> linked_list = LinkedList()
>>> insert_at_end(linked_list, 10)
>>> insert_at_end(linked_list, 42)
>>> insert_at_end(linked_list, 'foo')
>>> print_ll(linked_list)
10 42 foo
```

Comment: Martijn, I tried that earlier but it didn't work either.Thanks though

Comment: @Gabzmann: so how did you test that? You don't define what *didn't work* means here, so I can't help you further. The above is certainly the correct method.

Comment: @Gabzmann: your question would be much improved if you a) included your other attempt, b) showed your input and expected output and c) show us what happens instead (including any errors). That's called a [mcve].

Comment: Added a picture

Comment: @Gabzmann your code is not complete. Compare what you show in the screenhot with what my function does.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to add the `__iter__()` magic method to your LinkedList to make it iterable:

```
    def __iter__(self):
        current = self.head
        while current is not None:
            yield current
            current = current.next
        else:
            raise StopIteration
```

Now you can do iterate through nodes to add to the tail:

```
    def add_tail(self, item):
        if self.is_empty():
            self.add(item)
            return

        # Loop to the end of the list and add the item at the end.
        for node in self:
            pass
        else:
            node.next = Node(item, node.next)
```

Adding the `__iter__()` magic method also has the benefit that you can use iteration for things like constructing a string representation of the linked list. By defining the `__str__()` magic method, you're able to use `print(my_list)` to print something like `2->3->5`, and it's very easy to do with a list comprehension if you have an `__iter__()` method defined.

Note that this is actually the same as [the answer given by @MartijnPieters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40192539/539810), except it's in a different form. You're still looping through the list until you get to the end and adding the item at the end.